# nginx error 404 when requesting php files from an aliased location,

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi

I'm trying to using nginx with apache and PHP on a windows2008R2 box.
This is working fine except when I'm asking for a php file inside an "aliased" location. The directory listing is showing the php files but when I want to execute it, I get a 404 error.

what I want is an alias (http://myserver/asure) that will point to E:\www\asure\public.

Here is the nginx config

```
 server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  host00;        
        root   e:/www/ ;
        autoindex on;
        autoindex_exact_size off;
        autoindex_localtime on;

        location / {        
            index  index.php index.html index.htm;
        }

        location /asure/ {
            alias   "E:/www/ASURE/public/" ;
            #index index.php ;
            location ~ \.php$ {

                fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index  index.php;
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

            }
        }
}
```

Comment: any reason you are using `alias` instead of `root` ?

Comment: yes : root is appending the name of the location (will result in E:/www/ASURE/public/ASURE/ )

Comment: No. I have abandoned and stick with apache